# Not-In filter not available in couchbaselite swift

Tags: swift, couchbase-lite

Not-in filter not supported in CouchbaseLite, is there any workarround other then having several not-equal with AND?

I want opposite of the following expression

```
let query = QueryBuilder
                .select(
                    SelectResult.all()
                )
                .from(
                    DataSource.collection("Fruits")
                )
                .where(Expression.property("name").in(["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]))
```